# Seek row in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

How can I seek those rows which contain some text and get a mark depending on how many times this text was repeated?

- I have SQL Server CTP3 installed but I don't know where to start
- Maybe I can use `like %criteria%` and then count how many times the text is repeated on each record but it doesn't seem very efficient.
- It would be great if there was any routine on SQL Server for doing it

Comment: Can you do this in two passes?

Comment: What do you mean by mark? Can you not just use count() with a where clause?

Comment: Check out [SQL Server Fulltext Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) which allows just that... It's the [CONTAINSTABLE function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, I suggest you use a text to word list function. There's a few examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106275/how-to-get-a-distinct-list-of-words-used-in-all-field-records-using-ms-sql). If using full-text indexing, you could even use CONTAINSTABLE. You can then join to this table value function and aggregate the count.

```
 Select t.*, 
    (Select count(w.*) 
     From dbo.getWordList(t.text) w
     Where w.word like '%criteria%') as Count
 From MyTable t
 Where t.text like '%criteria%'
```

Alternatively you could just solve the entire problem in a CLR function.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna get the appearance times of string in a single SQL Server data record, the RegEx would be more appropriate.