# Split field and insert words into table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table

```
Create Table Keywords (keyword nvarchar(100))
```

I would like to split all of my email subjects and insert them into  my Keywords table.

```
This is an email
The cats and Dogs mailing
```

I want each word to return as rows.

Comment: Split email subject with spaces from a sentence.

Comment: Yes so that each word is a new row

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Can you update your question in detail?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split string and insert values into table in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885076/how-to-split-string-and-insert-values-into-table-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function like this one:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplit] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END
```

And select with this

```
select *
from dbo.fnSplit('This is an email
The cats and Dogs mailing',' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach.  It looks stranger, but it can actually perform faster than substringing.

```
declare   @string nvarchar(max) = 'This is  an email'
declare   @xml  xml

-- Convert your string to an XML fragment
set @xml = convert(xml, 
       '<tag keyword="' + replace(@string, ' ', '" /><tag keyword= "') + '" />');

-- Query your XML fragment for keyword nodes
with Keywords as (
    select  T.c.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as keyword
    from    @xml.nodes('/tag/@keyword') as T(c)
)
select *
from   Keywords
where  keyword > ''  -- Remove blank entries caused by multiple spaces
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you might want to avoid putting in duplicates and get unique words in there or add a column and update the counter to know how many times the word had appeared in a subject line.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106275/how-to-get-a-distinct-list-of-words-used-in-all-field-records-using-ms-sql) could very well work for you with a little tweak.

Questions?